# How can I write a text without using repetitive structures?

Tags: sentence-construction

Consider these sentences:

1. > It provides an analytical tool for investigation of the key parameters of the system.

(To me, everything looks fine except two consecutive **of**s.)

2. > It provides an analytical tool to investigate key parameters of the system.

The question is if both have the same meaning?

Can we write a sentence without using both **to+infinitive** and multiple **of**s ? I don't want to use repetitive structures in a thesis, article, ...  unless there is no other option.

Comment: I think the second one sounds better – but it has nothing to do with the "two consecutive ofs". There's nothing wrong with consecutive _of_ prepositional phrases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems with *hypernominalization*—overusing derivative nouns where their parent verbs would be simpler—is that it leads to piling up preposition phrases. I congratulate you on finding the solution: revert to a verbform whose object can be expressed with a noun phrase instead of a PP.

In this case you can do even better: you can eliminate a *to* by using a gerund instead of an infinitive, and you can eliminate the second *of* by using a possessive.

> It provides an analytical tool for investigating the system's key parameters.